# Not able to install "robustHD" in R on m1 mac

Tags: r, package

Laptop specs: macos big sur, m1 chip

Using Rstudio through Anaconda Nov2020 release. Following is the complete message that I get.

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/robustHD_0.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 129193 bytes (126 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 126 KB

* installing *source* package ‘robustHD’ ...
** package ‘robustHD’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c corHuber.cpp -o corHuber.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fastGrplars.cpp -o fastGrplars.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fastLars.cpp -o fastLars.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fastLasso.cpp -o fastLasso.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fastRlars.cpp -o fastRlars.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fastSparseLTS.cpp -o fastSparseLTS.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c initialSubsets.cpp -o initialSubsets.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c robustHD_init.c -o robustHD_init.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c utils.cpp -o utils.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib -L/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib -o robustHD.dylib corHuber.o fastGrplars.o fastLars.o fastLasso.o fastRlars.o fastSparseLTS.o initialSubsets.o robustHD_init.o utils.o -L/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/lib -lRlapack -L/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/lib -lRblas -L/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/_build_env/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5 -L/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/_build_env/lib/gcc -L/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/_build_env/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -fopenmp -L/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/lib -lR -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/_build_env/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/_build_env/lib/gcc'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/_build_env/lib'
ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: robustHD.dylib] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustHD’
* removing ‘/opt/anaconda3/envs/Env1/lib/R/library/robustHD’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘robustHD’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/fh/k_wtqk494dsdfkm31ttbr9k40000gn/T/RtmpBhUk6y/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a compiling issue of a source package. This issue is resolved in r releases greater than 4.0.0. So I followed a comment in the following thread to create a new environment and installed the packages. (I already had installed x-code SDK & command line tools)

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/77335/anconda-r-version-how-to-upgrade-to-4-0-and-later/86905#86905?newreg=85fd9c9a295d41d7975481f6261b06ea